# Using SignalR in ASP.NET Core with Angular JS

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, signalr

I am using a SignalR with ASP.NET MVC(server side) and AngularJS (client side) which work fine but now my boss asked me to update singalR server to ASP.Net core, I searched a lot on internet but can't find an example or demo where Angular JS used as client with ASP.NET core so my question is this, can we use AngularJS as a SignalR client with ASP.Net Core Server ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to connect signalR from angularJs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39656038/how-to-connect-signalr-from-angularjs)

Comment: Hi, we are facing a similar migration. Our work is still in progress but, anyway, the client side library for asp.net core signalr is just a javascript library; you have a class letting you creating new objects which you use to communicate with the server. You can use that stuff inside angularjs services and controllers because that's all javascript at the end of the day. What are your concerns ?

Comment: its not duplicate , they are not even using asp.net core

Comment: Take a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio). The client side library is used to create a connection object which you have to configure and then to start so that you can start communicate with the server. That's plain old javascript, there is nothing preventing you from using that stuff from angularjs building blocks (services, controllers, modules and so on...)

Comment: hi @EnricoMassone thanks for a link , i am new to angular js that's why i  just want to make sure , anyway i got it now thanks again :)

Comment: Similar problem i am facing. Getting 405 Method Not Allowed while establishing negotiate connection with SignalR server URL. If you find anything please let me know @MuhammadFaisal